# Proving conjugate property of Frobenius inner product over the complex field

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The Frobenius inner product defined by 
Inner product of A,B=trace(B*A), where ,
B*=conjugate of  B transpose, over the complex field. I need help in proving the property that, Conjugate of Inner product of A,B = Inner product of B,A
Can anyone please help me out in proving this particular property. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $A$ has entries $A_{ij}$ and $B%$ has entries $B_{ij}$, then
$$\langle A,B \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}\overline{B_{ij}}\,.$$
That is, $\langle A,B \rangle$ is just as the dot product in $\mathbb F^N$ with $N=n^2$ (first you multiply each entry of the first vector with the conjugate of the respective entry of the second vector, then you add all). Can you finish from here?

Comment: But here the inner product is defined differently. It is not the usual inner product like you have mentioned here.

Comment: Yes, it is, just expand the trace and the product $B^*A$.

Comment: Yes, yes, you are right. Initially I misunderstood it.

Comment: Yes, I have solved the rest. Thankyou for the hint.

Comment: But I have one more question. Is conjugate of B\*A=A\*B , as a whole in two matrices, not just trace ?

Comment: You're welcome! In fact it is very useful note that writing the product in that way reduces working with matrices with vectors in $\mathbb F^N$. Sorry, I don't get your last question, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean are the two matrix multiplication same -- conjugate of B\*A and A\*B

Comment: You mean $\overline{B^*A} = A^*B$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you got it right

Comment: Not necessarily, what about if $B$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is not symmetric?

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thankyou

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109102/discussion-between-esha-and-azif00).